# What text matches this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure it out what kind of text would match the following regex, but I can't find a match.

```
^(\d{3}-){2}\d{4}$
```

This string

```
(111-)(111-)4444
```

doesn't match.

I think it should be 3 digits and a minus at the end, between parenthesis, and this entire expression repeated twice, followed by a 4 digit number.

What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: It doesn't match parentheses, they're part of the regex syntax. So `111-111-4444` will match.

Comment: `555-555-5555` should match: http://www.regexplained.co.uk/?pattern=%5E(%5Cd%7B3%7D-)%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B4%7D%24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis is a regex metacharacter.  If you want to match a literal parenthesis, you need to backslash-escape it (in many regex dialects).

```
^(\(\d{3}-\)){2}\d{4}$
```

A bare parenthesis doesn't match anything; it's used for grouping and capturing.  For example, `^(a|b)$` matches either `a` or `b`.  The parentheses group the alteration `|` so that the stuff outside the parentheses is required regardless of which expression inside the parenthesis group matched.  Similarly, in the above, the unescaped parentheses govern what the `{2}` repeats (without the group, it would simply repeat the final `\)`).

If your language offers capture groups, `$1` or `\1` or `m.group(1)` or whatever it's called will contain whatever was inside the first pair of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you tripleee for your answer, it helped me to understand what was i doing wrong.
Salutations

Answer (score 2):

The brackets are regex groups, not literal brackets. So this is a match:

```
111-111-4444
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/bH0oM0/1) at Regex101.

Comment: I think you mean "parentheses" instead of "brackets".

Comment: @l'L'l it's a regional thing. See e.g. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14252/what-is-the-common-name-for-brackets-braces-and-parentheses

Comment: Ah! Thank you for pointing that out – I had no idea, and hopefully no offense taken.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and helping me out!!
I will check out the site.
Salutations

Comment: None taken, @l'L'l. No problem, Kouen.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://regex101.com if you want to test out your regexes.

The \d is a digit and can be anything 0, 1,2,3...,9.

The {3} means, exactly 3 occurrences of the digit. So 143, 768, etc.

344-644-2319 will match that regex.

Comment: Thank you Jim for your answer i am a beginner with regexes and didn´t know about sites that makes your programming easier.
Salutations.